# Create multiple consumers for same topic and not duplication offset in kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

**My problem**

I have one producer. produce message two times "hello1", "hello2" to topic name t1.
And I have 2 consumer name c1,c2. 
So I want c1 consumer message "hello1" and c2 consume message "hello2".

**But** now when I consume message c1 get "hello1", "hello2" and c2 get "hello1", "hello2" too.
I don't want it.

**Question**

How could I create 2 or 3 consumers to subscribe messages from the same topic without duplicate message.

Comment: I got your idea but my case is not like this.
I would like to consume messages no duplicate value.
Ex  : 1  I create one topic name: "t1"
2 I produce message "hello1" to topic t1 
3 I produce message "hello2" to topic t1 
4 I create two consumer names [c1 and c2] to subscribe to that message from the topic"t1".
I want c1 and c2 subcrib message as parallel not single consumer.
So I want c1 to subscribe message "hello1" and c2 subscribe message "hello2". a
I know this situation is a little weird for you.
But I need this for business login for me.
Do you have any idea more about that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to have both consumers in the same Consumer Group. Within a Consumer Group, a message will only be consumed by a single consumer.

You can set the Group a consumer belongs to using the `group.id` setting. See http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs for the details about this setting.

See [this section](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#kafka_mq) from the docs that covers the basics about Consumer Groups

Comment: I got your idea but my case is not like this.I would like to consume messages no duplicate value

Comment: In this case impossible or not? @Mickael Maison

Comment: You cannot have 2 consumers "sharing" messages from the same partitions at the same time.
T1 needs to have multiple partitions (p1 and p2). In that case, if message1 is written to p1 and message2 written to p2 then if the consumers are in a group, 1 consumer will get the messages from p1 and the other from p2.

Comment: Yes, I got it now it work for me :D just create a consumer group and define partition.count so c1 and c2 will rebalance c1 get from p1, c2 get from c2.